# Fit 2 A5 pdf into ONE PAGE A4 Landscape

Tags: linux, bash, pdf, slack

I have been working on Linux Slackware for several years and
programming in bash for routine things.

My problem is printing books in sewn booklets of 4 sheets. With a bash script I order the 16 pages so  that they are sequential in the dossier (front 16-1, back 2-15, front 14-3, back 4-13 etc.)

Since the books are in html I transform them into
PDF format A5 with `wkhtmltopdf`. After that, with bash scripts, I split  into individual PDF pages with separate PDFs.

I gave it a try with  GhostScript, but the problem is that the pages, even if they are  correctly left and right (2 x A5 -> A4 landscape), are printed on two different pages.

I have read all the discussions, including those on this site, but I am astonished that To do this you need 7 different commands (`pdfcrop`, `pdftocairo`, `pdfinfo`, `python`, `pdfjam`, `latex` and `dvipdfm`) and you can not put the two pages side by side With only GS  commands or at least with commands already installed in my operating system.

I also tried with `pdftk`, which I can not install on my system due to
Incompatible jar libraries. I attach my bash script that does the job as  mentioned. Everywhere I find only answers to "MERGE" multiple pdf
documents, which can be done nicely with the command `pdfunite`, but no
one says how to merge 2 A5pdf in A4 Landscape.

Thanks to anyone who give me a help.
PS> Ghostcript code

`gqs -o myouput.pdf-sDEVICE=pdfwrite -g8420x5950 -c "<</PageOffset[0 0]>> setpagedevice" -f myleftpage.pdf -c "<</PageOffset[421 0]>> setpagedevice" -f myrightpage.pdf`

Comment: Hi, It would be more readable if it was split into paragraphs

Comment: <code>gqs -o myouput.pdf-sDEVICE=pdfwrite -g8420x5950 -c "<</PageOffset[0 0]>> 
setpagedevice" -f myleftpage.pdf  -c "<</PageOffset[421 0]>> setpagedevice" -f myrightpage.pdf</code>

Comment: I don't know why that code is your response to very accurate "split paragraphs" suggestions. That code should be placed into the question with explantation about what doesn't work, unless you instantly found an answer, then ou should think if it was worth writing that block.

Comment: If I am reading you correctly, `cpdf -impose-xy "2 1" in.pdf -o out.pdf` should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

The `texlive-extra-utils` packages has a [`a5toa4` tool](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/texlive-extra-utils/a5toa4.1.en.html) that does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you can create with [`wkhtmltopdf`](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) a *normal* A4 file, the following `pdfjam`<sup>[[1](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/pdfjam.1.html),[2](https://github.com/rrthomas/pdfjam),[3](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pdfjam)]</sup> command should work as per your wishes

```
pdfjam --landscape --signature 16 main.pdf
```

Note that signature has to be a multiple of 4.

In case you cannot create a unique file from different html sources you will need a step more merging the single pdf files into a final one (give it a look to pdfarranger<sup>[[4](https://github.com/pdfarranger/pdfarranger)]</sup>).
When you convert to pdf you may want to use font bigger than usual because you know it will be printed as booklet.

---

ps> probably it should work directly

```
pdfbook  foo.pdf
```

pps> What about pdfbooklet <sup>[[5](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/572)]</sup>? Did you give it a try?

---

The OP solved the problem uninstalling TeX, installing TeX-live, adding the required paths to `$PATH`, obtaining a working version of `pdfjam` on his system. Then the minimal command was:

```
pdfjam pageleft.pdf pageright.pdf --nup 2x1 --landscape --outfile mydoublelandscape.pdf
```

Comment: I wrote I have SO Slackware. To install package in Slack we need pre- compiled package and "apt get install" here don't work. Pdfjam pdfbook not are previuos package. I think this problem can solved on ghostscript. The code I had joint is THE PROBLEM and I am new on this site: I joint it from telephone and is not easy. From PC I'm unable to sign in.

Comment: No Claudio, you wrote that are several years that you were working on Slack. And you tag this question as Linux. BTW nessun problema. It seems you have installed LaTex. From link #2 (GitHub) of this answer you can read: _For some years now, pdfjam has been included in the TeX Live distribution, which includes all the necessary programs and packages to make pdfjam run smoothly. If you have the necessary bandwidth and disk space for it, I do recommend installing TeX Live._  So if you have LaTex on your system and you may install the LaTex package `pdfpages`you should be able to use it.

Comment: @ClaudioChicco I tried the command above on my system (a different one) and it worked. ps>Welcome on SuperUser

Comment: Tanks Hastur. I search in SlackBuild but I've no tesult for tex live. Alls the suggested command make "command not found" in bash. In another thread I read "ghostscript" can merge 2 file but the solution suggested was pdftk, and I can not install it. I apilogize gs solution! Tanks!

Comment: Tkanks to Hasthur and alls. I have install Latex Live, uninstall old version of latex and finally $PATH to dir. The command that solve my problem is                <code> pdfjam pageleft.pdf pageright.pdf --nup 2x1 --landscape --outfile mydoublelandscape.pdf</code>           Anyone can mark "solved"?   Tanks to all!

Comment: @ClaudioChicco You're welcome. No, you are the (only) one that can upvote and check the answer to say that the problem was solved... I modify my answer with your update.

Comment: Sorry I do not know how to vote and mark solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Booklet printing is a variation on N-UP and for 16 pages "should be simple"

There are many complex ways I have described using LaTeX as saddle stitches method for upto 32 pages here adapted for 32 x A5 Landscape page spreads across 8 A3 Landscape flats https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/494232 but easily adaptable for say 16 on  different media

Here is the signature for the 32 page layout [image]

However for 16 conventional pages we can use simpler means
Possibly TL;DR is an overview based on using SumatraPDF in Windows as https://github.com/GitHubRulesOK/MyNotes/blob/master/AppNotes/SumatraPDF/Addins/N-Up-PDF/N-Up-PDF.pdf (so avoid those if wanting simplicity :-)

What is needed is any N-Up command tool that reorders into booklet layout with rotations.

And cross platform there are tools such as cpdf (not free for commercial use but good value) also qpdf (free but perhaps unwieldy for this task) pdftk (perhaps too old, in some cases) and new kid on the block pdfcpu

The example shows only 8 page layout but 16 is just 2 of those!

https://pdfcpu.io/generate/booklet
[image]